# Static функции в C

Tags: c, функции, static

Не могу до конца понять смысл `static` функций.
Я понимаю, что оно ограничивает видимость, но ведь она и так изначально ограничена.
И я не могу вызвать функцию из другой единицы, если не объявил ее изначально в текущей единице трансляции.
При этом, `static` функцию я все равно не могу указывать в `*.h` файле, и ее приходится объявлять в `*.c` файлах.

Получается, что и так и так, объявление локальных функций приходится делать в `*.c` и вызвать ее оттуда, без явного намерения (объявить в `*.h` или объявить `extern`) не получится.
Зачем тогда `static`? Чтобы перестраховываться от этого?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` не имеет никакого отношения к *видимости* вообще. Видимость - свойство *идентификатора*, на которое `static` не оказывает никакого влияния.

Объявление функции как `static` придает ей *внутреннее связывание*, то есть ограничивает ее *линкуемость* из других единиц трансляции. Все ссылки на `static`-сущности обычно разрешаются на стадии компиляции и в генерируемом объектном файле не упоминаются вообще, т.е. линкер даже и не знает об их существовании. В частности, нет никакой необходимости беспокоиться о глобальных конфликтах имен при объявлении статических функций.

Ваши рассуждения на тему "могу объявить" или "не могу объявить" не совсем ясны. К функции с *внешним* связыванием вы всегда можете прилинковаться из другой единицы трансляции - достаточно просто выполнить ее объявление. К функции с *внутренним* связыванием (т.е. `static`-функции) вы прилинковаться из другой единицы трансляции никак не сможете. Разница налицо.

Также объявление функций как `static` дает компилятору исчерпывающее знание о всех контекстах вызова этой функции, что существенно повышает его возможности по оптимизации кода. (Известный интереснейший пример, в том числе существенно опирающийся на свойства `static`: [Why undefined behavior may call a never-called function](https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/09/why-undefined-behavior-may-call-never.html))

Comment: Касательно моих рассуждений. Я к тому, что объявление функции в другой единицы трансляции это явное действие, не ошибка и намеренно пытаться сделать ее к static никто не будет по определению, а вызвать ее без объявления в принципе не возможно, т.к. в подключаемом H файле ее не будет. Надеюсь, я ясно изложил свою мысль, хотя по моему - нет.
Если совсем в кратце - static функция, это просто защита, даже не от человеческой ошибки, а от дурака, пытающегося вызвать то, что никто не предполагал для вызова?

Comment: "А вызвать ее без объявления в принципе не возможно". Да, но если функция не является `static`, то никто вам не запрещает самому ручками написать ее объявление в любом месте своего кода. И тут же вызвать. Никаких заголовочных файлов не нужно. Так что все возможно.

Comment: И это единственное предназначение `static`? Не дать собственноручно собрать оружие и лишится колена?

Comment: Предназначение у `static` вполне конкретное: не захламлять глобальное пространство линкуемых символов именами, которые там совсем не нужны. А все остальное - лишь побочные эффекты этого предназначения.

Comment: Так еще понятнее. Но у меня все равно не получается для себя сделать правильный вывод - стоит ли всегда делать внутренние функции `static`, 
Или это просто излишняя педантичность?
Потому, что судя по всему пользы человеку от этого никакой нет, а причин, по которым меня должны волновать проблемы линковщика, я не вижу.

Comment: @AnT, у статьи есть перевод: https://habr.com/ru/company/infopulse/blog/338812/. Кстати, он даже подробнее оригинала выглядит :) А, понял - там ещё продолжение тоже.

Comment: @segar, это не только проблема линковщика. Это еще и (нередко) проблема командной разработки. Когда имена всех Ваших функций находятся в глобальном пространстве имен, с ростом проекта и команды существенно растет шанс на то, что у кого-то может оказаться функция с таким-же именем. И вот мы уже получаем конфликт имен....

Comment: Т.е.в файле A.c фунция Foo() и в файле B.c функция Foo(), при условии, что они не используются в одной единице трансляции, проект не соберется?

Comment: @segar: Это не важно, используются они или не используются. Если у вас есть две одноименные функции с внешним связыванием - компиляция (линковка) не пройдет. Вы получите сообщение об ошибке множественного определения.

Comment: Вот это окончательно прояснило. Спасибо.